# deploy Ubuntu SDK qml app to Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm wondering if its possible to deploy an app made with the Ubuntu SDK in qml to Windows or Mac? and also to other distros which I think should be possible through a snap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used parts that depend on Unity or phone-specific devices, it's possible to get some part of the Ubuntu-Components compile on Windows or Mac.

If there are no Ubuntu-Components used - then it's an ordinary Qt application that can be compiled for anything.